# What is the preferred dpi for Adobe Illustrator when designing for WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend, expression, adobe-illustrator

My designer is sending me files from Adobe illustrator that are 72dpi.
I'm having some problems when I use the shapes after importing into Expression.
The actual size in Expression looks fine - It imports at 72 dpi.
The shapes are much bigger on my screen when I run the WPF app however, I assume because my desktop resolution is set to 96 dpi. Should I request that the designer switch to 96dpi? or should I just take care of this some how in Expression?

Comment: If you switch to 96dpi so it looks fine on your screen, wouldn't it then shrink for users that have 72dpi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my issue. Adobe Illustrator files are fine. The import in Expression makes the document 72 pixels per inch. Going into expression and changing the document size to 96 pixels per inch does not indicate that it will change the document width/height when you hit ok unless you tab off of it first - This is what got me. You have to change to 96 pixels per inch then tab off -Expression then will then suggest a new width and height which is much bigger. I had to manually put this back to where it was.
The artwork looks great and the xaml I'm extracting looks great in the wpf app.

In case anyone was curious, this is for a Kiosk app that will be running at 96dpi. The wpf app needs to look exactly like the illustrator files.